# How do I allow users to download a MIDI file with Flask without getting a 0 byte download?

Tags: python, flask, midi

I am writing an application that creates a midi file using the MIDIUtil library. When the user submits an HTML form, a midi file object is created with MIDIUtil. How do I allow the user to download this as a .mid file? I have tried the following code, but I end up downloading a file of 0 bytes.

```
return Response(myMIDIFile, mimetype='audio/midi')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this, and it worked.

```
new_file = open('test.mid', 'wb')
myMIDI.writeFile(new_file)
new_file.close()
new_file = open('test.mid', 'rb')
return send_file(new_file, mimetype='audio/midi')
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a variant of the following code to allow my users to download images they generate. The below code should work for you. Please note that you will most likely need to specify the full server path to the file being downloaded.

```
from flask import send_file

download_filename = FULL_PATH_TO_YOUR_MIDI_FILE

return(send_file(filename_or_fp = download_filename,mimetype="audio/midi",as_attachment=True))
```

Answer (score -1):

Might want to just try using send_file

```
from flask import send_file

return send_file("yourmidifile.mid", as_attachement=True, mimetype="audio\midi")
```

Comment: audio/midi NOT audio\midi.